# Failed Request Tracing XML fails to display in Internet Explorer (IIS 7.5)

Tags: iis-7.5, log-files, debugging, asp-classic, iis

I have installed the Tracing feature and enabled failed request tracing for a website, to debug a Classic ASP website. The XML logs are created upon occurring errors, however when I open them in IE, instead of getting the nice blue interface I get a massive amount of code/text.

Why doesn't the interface load and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out I was missing the freb.xsl file, so I downloaded one from here (link at the bottom of the page): http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/10/19/Making-Failed-Request-Tracing-More-Approachable.aspx

Hope someone will find this helpful. :)

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem on a fresh install of Windows 2012. However, the freb.xsl file was present in the same folder as the event XML file.

To get it to show the 'nice interface' I had to add "about:internet" to the IE11 trusted sites list, as discussed here: http://forums.iis.net/p/1147605/1862016.aspx

Comment: adding about:internet to trusted sites worked

Comment: adding about:internet to trusted sites did not work for me. I have ie version 11.0.9600.17728

Comment: This worked for me in IE but not in Edge

Comment: Everything Microsoft is pulling teeth, even the simplest things.

Comment: Well, Edge will never work because it doesn't support rendering XSLT anymore because Chromium doesn't support that. You'll have to use Internet Explorer mode or a dedicated log viewer app if you can't use IE.

Answer (score 6):

If the freb.xsl file is missing from the directory that contains the log files, then the nice interface won't show.  Rather than trying to find a website with the latest freb.xsl, I found on this page:

http://blogs.iis.net/davcox/archive/2007/10/05/recovering-freb-xsl-after-deleting-it.aspx

that if you just delete the directory that the xml files are being written to (likely something like C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC1), then IIS will automatically recreate the directory and write the freb.xsl file when it next creates the next log file.

Comment: Just be careful to save off first whatever xml files might be in that directory you are going to delete, as they might have the very Failed Request Trace info you wanted to view. that's why I think the other answer focused on getting the xsl file. But for some folks, sure, your suggestion is a worthy solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

I got the failed request trace to display in IE (and it doesn't work on chrome) by pointing an IIS website at the folder and open it in IE - version 11 - from there.

Other things I tried before this was

1. add `about:internet` to trusted sites
2. to run in compatibility mode.

I am certain this has to do with security settings and there is probably an easier way of getting this to work without IIS. I go with the path of least resistance on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but this solution worked for me (thanks Pilau)
I downloaded this [file](http://www.iis.net/media/7433929/freb.zip) and copied to C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC2

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to disable the **Enhanced Protected Mode** of Internet Explorer.

To do so go to...
IE menu → Tools → Internet Options → Advanced → Scroll down to section "Security" → **Disable** Checkbox "Enable Enhanced Protected Mode"

Make sure that you **fully restart IE** for this change to take effect.